# Google Apps Script to refresh stock chart image from URL

Tags: image, url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, refresh

How can I set up a Google Apps Script (or other method) to refresh a stock chart image using the image URL each time the sheet is viewed or on a periodic basis?

For example I have the following image in my Google Sheets file:
http://etf.bannronn.com/stocks/genchart.php?symbol=VOO

...but it is not updating when I load the sheet on following days even though I added the image using the URL(I've compared the charts to be sure).

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: For google apps script see their dashboard api

Answer (score 3):

You can append a unique value to the URL so that each time the sheet opens the URL changes though technically it is still the same.

For instance, you can say:

```
= image("http://etf.bannronn.com/stocks/genchart.php?symbol=VOO" + "#" + rand());
```

Comment: Maybe something changed in Google Spreadsheets but I had to change th "+" to "&". `=image("http://etf.bannronn.com/stocks/genchart.php?symbol=VOO#"&rand());`